# google drive backup and restore restore one app

Tags: adb, google-drive

I have a OnePlus 6t and factory reset it a few days ago because it was really slow (btw the problem is still not solved, also my fingerprint sensor doesn't work anymore, may be linked). I did my backup locally (only sms and photos) and on the Google Drive service (everything saved there, always enabled and saves everything).

My problem is that I had more than 2000 solves of my time solving the cube, I always tracked my progress. I can't anymore because I lost the data as it was not saved locally. I don't want the data of the other apps, I would like to get only the data from this app, the name of the app is twisty timer.

I tried to use adb and bmgr, but I can't manage to make it work. I do not find the package name, it seems to be com.aricneto.twistytimer... And when I try to restore from the old save nothing works, and it says in logcat

PM agent has not metadata
And in the shell console, restoredFinished -1000. I don't know what to do and how to do. Can somebody help me ?

I tried to so the same with other apps, there are two backups (of the same phone), one before reset, one after. I manage to restore from the new backup files, but not from the old ones. I don't know if there is a much simpler solution. I can see the app exist in Google Drive in the app in the old backup, but I can't do anything with it.

Found this great resource on the famous internet

edit : Here are the screens of what I mean

A few tries with bmgr :

https://snipboard.io/nfiaMe.jpg

All the sets in bmgr (old and new saves)

https://snipboard.io/4qeJWD.jpg

The Google Drive app on my phone showing the app (twisty timer)

https://snipboard.io/5J1UcY.jpg

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't paste terminal output in screen shots. Just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as "code".